# R - How to add a column with a grouped mean of a column over x days

Tags: r

I'm looking to add a column in R to my data frame that gives me the mean of a value grouped by account over the past 5 days.

My initial data looks like this:

```
row  account    date         col1    col2    value
1    1          01/01/2015   5       2       10
2    1          02/01/2015   3       9       19
3    1          15/01/2015   7       4       16
4    1          18/01/2015   1       3       22
5    2          16/01/2015   4       2       16
6    2          24/01/2015   10      8       25
7    2          30/01/2015   9       2       24
8    2          30/01/2015   8       7       11
```

And I am looking for this:

```
row  account    date         col1    col2    value    avg_5
1    1          01/01/2015   5       2       10       10
2    1          02/01/2015   3       9       19       14.5
3    1          15/01/2015   7       4       16       16
4    1          18/01/2015   1       3       22       19
5    2          16/01/2015   4       2       16       16
6    2          24/01/2015   10      8       25       25
7    2          30/01/2015   9       2       24       24
8    2          30/01/2015   8       7       11       17.5
```

The 5-day mean for row 1 is 10 since its value is 10 and there were no other rows in the past 5 days. For row 4, however, it is 9 as the value is 22 and in the past 5 days (since the 14/01/2015) there has been one row with the value 10.

I managed to get the difference in days using this:

```
df$ddate <- as.vector(unlist(tapply(df$date, df$account, FUN=function(x) { return (c(NA, diff(x))) } )))
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?

**UPDATE**

@akruns answer is very close to what I need. Only problem I have is that it only works if the max. amount of rows in the period is 2. If I have for example 3 values it gets a bit messed up (I used 29 day mean instead of 5 in the following):

```
#  gr  account   date          value     avg_29
1  1   1         2014-03-19    100.00    100.0000
2  2   1         2014-05-06    100.00    100.0000
3  2   1         2014-05-21    209.70    111.4133   *Should be 154.85
4  2   1         2014-05-26    24.54     111.4133
5  3   1         2014-07-26    44.04     44.0400
```

Comment: I have a doubt about your description and the code.  Suppose, your date is `date <- seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), length.out=20, by= 'day')`, then would you take the mean of values for the entire date period as there were no breaks or is it a running mean of 5 day period i.e. first mean would be the first value, second the first two values, ..., fifth the mean of first five, then 2:6, 3:7, and so on...

Comment: I'm not looking for a running mean of 5 days but only the past five days to each row with respect to the account. The first mean would be the first value and the second the first two. The third would, however, be only the third value as there are no other rows in the period 11/01/2015 to 15/01/2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(date= as.Date(date, '%d/%m/%Y')) %>%
  group_by(account) %>%
  arrange(date) %>% 
  group_by(gr = cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(date)>5)), add=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(avg_5 = cummean(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-gr)
#  row account       date col1 col2 value avg_5
#1   1       1 2015-01-01    5    2    10  10.0
#2   2       1 2015-01-02    3    9    19  14.5
#3   3       1 2015-01-15    7    4    16  16.0
#4   4       1 2015-01-18    1    3    22  19.0
#5   5       2 2015-01-16    4    2    16  16.0
#6   6       2 2015-01-24   10    8    25  25.0
#7   7       2 2015-01-30    9    2    24  24.0
#8   8       2 2015-01-30    8    7    11  17.5
```

For the second dataset

```
df2 %>%
   mutate(date=as.Date(date))%>%
   group_by(account) %>%
   arrange(date) %>%
   group_by(gr = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(date)>29)), add = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(avg_29=cummean(amount)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   select(-gr)
# account       date amount   avg_29
#1     1 2014-03-19 100.00 100.0000 
#2     1 2014-05-06 100.00 100.0000
#3     1 2014-05-21 209.70 154.8500
#4     1 2014-05-26  24.54 111.4133
#5     1 2014-07-26  44.04  44.0400
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(account = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
 date = c("2014-03-19", 
"2014-05-06", "2014-05-21", "2014-05-26", "2014-07-26"), amount = c(100, 
100, 209.7, 24.54, 44.04)), .Names = c("account", "date", "amount"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: @shatala Can you update your post with a new example and the expected result?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I did not realise formatting did not work in comments :)